# Symfony No route found for GET /undefined

Tags: php, symfony

I have a little problem, i put my symfony website online yesterday, every thing works fine but i got a random problem.
Everytime i click on the button to go back one page i got the error: "No route found for GET /undefined"
This error also pop randomly when i click on links on my website.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hello. First of all for security reasons you should not let anybody access to your dev environement (app_dev.php) . I can access to your console coresphere (app_dev.php/_console) .Secondly you should post your routing.yml to get a better help.

Comment: Okay thank you, i did what you said and i've updated my post

Comment: So when you click backspace you have this error ? "No route found for GET /undefined" ? I don't see that error when I click backspace

Comment: Yes, for example go to this page: http://lilian-cazabet.fr/category/Projets%20Personnels and click backspace, i got a 404 error...
Or simply got to "Galleries", click on one of them and click backspace

Comment: Ok I think I understand your problem. I think in your template you create link with something like category.name ? You should use slug. Show me how you create link in your template. For exemple how do you create this link in your twig template ? category/Projet Personnels

Comment: Maybe you're right, i've updated the post again with the twig

Comment: Can I ask why you are using Symfony for this? I know it's offtopic but I think a blogging platform like Wordpress would be a better fit for this project.

Comment: I think you should check the logs because the error is not consistent. At least not for me.

Comment: @TomásCot because i wanted to  learn symfony ...
In the logs there is written the same thing as in the title

Comment: Did you check the server logs? Because for me it fails after sending a bunch of requests.

Comment: So you store your catgeories in a category table in your database ?

Comment: Check the html where link is generated. Looks like a javascript error. 
"undefined" comes from an javascript

Comment: @Nandakumar the html doesn't seem to have any problem

Comment: `$("body").fadeOut(2000, redirectPage);` It seems problem is in this statement in your main.js.

Comment: @AnkitVadi Thank you very much, it was simply that !!!

Comment: I have glad that my observation and answer was useful to solve your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First problem:

You need to have links with this pattern "*Projets-Personnels*" instead of "Projets Personnels". That's what we call a "slug"

Install doctrine extension *sluggable* so Doctrine auto create the slug for you.

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html

When you will have this doctrine extension installed you will create your link like this:

```
{% for item in categories %}

            <h2 class="lp-title"> {{ item.slug}} </h2>

      {% endfor %}
```

Second problem:

About your backspace bug on firefox on Ubuntu:

You need to enable the backspace if you use Firefoxe in Ubuntu.

Go to the bar url of your firefox browser and execute this adress `about:config`

Firefox will show an avertissement message it's normal. Click ok. Then you need to change the value for `browser:backspace_action` from 2 to 0

I have tested this solution on Firefox Ubuntu and it works fine.

Comment: Okay thank you, i've added a slug, now the problem didn't happen again since i did this :)

But there is still the problm with back button, it's very strange because it only happen on my computer, not on my phone...

Comment: I have tried several times but never had the backspace bug when I browse your website. Which navigator do you use ?

Comment: Which "back" button do you click to get this bug ? An html button or do you mean the backspace on your keyboard ?

Comment: I just went to my website on another computer and the random problem is still there ... :( maybe its just the javascript  and i should take another template ...

Comment: I've just tried on ubuntu and firefox and yes I can see the bug.

Comment: Thanks, im not crazy ^^

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try to implement the solution. If it works for you don't forget to accept the answer please.

Comment: It was already at 2 and i have the same problem on windows :/

Comment: Im' sorry I edited my answer. You need to change 2 to 0.

Comment: then enable it also on windows.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work neither :/
It'es REALLY frustrating because when i click on the same link: "http://lilian-cazabet.fr/category/Reportages" sometimes it works and sometimes it goes to "http://lilian-cazabet.fr/undefined" ...

Comment: Edit your question and show your GelleryControlleur please

Comment: Maybe you need to activate the https. For firefox it is important that your site is in https.